# How to check dynamic model name in turnary condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I want to generate some expand/collapse arrows dynamically by ng-repeat and want to add class, that item is expanded or not using ternary condition:

```
<a ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]" ng-click="expandCollaps('selectedItem' + i.UniqueId)">
  <i class="material-icons {{selectedItem1 ? 'expanded' : '' }}">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
</a>
```

Angularjs function:

```
$scope.expandCollaps = function (modalName) {
  $scope[modalName] = $scope[modalName] ? false : true;
}
```

How can check ternary condition dynamically, like: selectedItem1, selectedItem2, selectedItem3

*Better if it is possible using directive..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` to achieve what you want.
Here is an example:

```
<a ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]" ng-click="itemSelected[i] = !itemSelected[i]">
    <i class="material-icons" ng-class="{expanded : itemSelected[i]}">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
</a>
```